# How can I create a trigger in sqlite database?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have to create trigger in my SQLite database.

There are 3 tables in database

- `questions (question_id)`
- `options (option_id, question_id)`
- `answers (answer_id, question_id)`

Whenever any row is deleted from `question` table, the corresponding data should also be deleted from `option` and `answer` tables.

I am trying to create trigger using

```
CREATE TRIGGER question_delete
BEFORE DELETE ON questions
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
DELETE from options WHERE question_id= OLD.question_id AND
DELETE from answers WHERE question_id= OLD.question_id;
END
```

I get an error. Should I create two different trigger to perform this operation or any changes are required in above statement?

Please let me know.

Thanks
Nidhi

Comment: **WHAT** error do you get?? It really doesn't help us to know you get "an error" - but you're not telling us what it is!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `AND` after the first `DELETE` statement:

```
DELETE from options WHERE question_id = OLD.question_id;
DELETE from answers WHERE question_id = OLD.question_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

try replacing the "AND" with ";" and it you still get an error, post the error's text here